# Neo4j access array of property to edit

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

Does anyone know how to access an array property of a node and change the value?

Is there some easy way in cypher like we do in C/C++/Java

array[index] = "some value"

I need to access an array element property of a node and change its value on specific conditions.

Answer (score 1):

For reading the n-th element of an array you can simply use the subscript operator:

```
return [1,2,3,4,5,6][2]
```

gives you the third element of the array, `3` in this case.

If you want to replace e.g. the 4th element of an array with a value of 999, you might use

```
with [1,2,3,4,5,6] as myarray
return myarray[0..3] + 999 + myarray[4..length(myarray)]
```